# What is the proper way of using the Demonstrative Pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: démonstratifs

I'm trying to get the appropriate translation for "This is my teacher.", but so far my research has led me nowhere.

Looking at the demonstrative pronouns in French, the right option would be "celui" but I can't think of how to form the structure.

*Celui-ci, c'est mon professeur.* Would this be the proper way?

How would a native person form this sentence?

Comment: Simply "C'est mon professeur" (or *Lui, c'est mon professeur*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the appropriate translation, you should provide more context as there are various situations where "This is my teacher" can be used in English. Depending on them, the French translation might vary. Here are some examples:

Introducing your teacher to someone else:

- *Voici mon professeur*.
- *Je vous présente mon professeur*.

Showing a photo of your teacher:

- *Voici mon professeur*.
- *C'est mon professeur*.
- *Lui/elle, c'est mon professeur*.

Showing your teacher among other people :

- *Celui-ci / celui-là / celle-ci / celle-là, c'est mon professeur*.

Notes:

- *Professeur* is written French and rarely used in spoken French unless formal speak, otherwise *prof* is used. *Prof* is both masculine and feminine while *professeur* generally stays masculine regardless of the teacher's gender.
- A primary school teacher will translate to *maitre* or *maitresse*.
- For higher levels, there is more than one teacher so usually what is taught is specified (e.g. *lui, c'est mon prof de math*, *elle, c'est ma prof d'espagnol*)